# I wrote this code to object tracking, but it gives an error:

Tags: numpy, opencv

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet("yolov3.weights", "yolov3.cfg")
layer_names = net.getLayerNames()
output_layers = [layer_names[i[0] - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]


video = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')

while True:
    ret, frame = video.read()
    if not ret:
        break

    height, width, channels = frame.shape


    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 0.00392, (416, 416), (0, 0, 0), True, crop=False)
    net.setInput(blob)
    outs = net.forward(output_layers)


    for out in outs:
        for detection in out:
            scores = detection[5:]
            class_id = np.argmax(scores)
            confidence = scores[class_id]
            if confidence > 0.5:
            
                center_x = int(detection[0] * width)
                center_y = int(detection[1] * height)
                w = int(detection[2] * width)
                h = int(detection[3] * height)

            
                x = int(center_x - w / 2)
                y = int(center_y - h / 2)
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)


    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)


    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27:
        break

video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

```
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet("yolov3.weights", "yolov3.cfg")
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.9.0) D:\\a\\opencv-python\\opencv-python\\opencv\\modules\\dnn\\src\\darknet\\darknet_io.cpp:960: error: (-212:Parsing error) Unknown layer type:  in function 'cv::dnn::darknet::ReadDarknetFromCfgStream'
```

Comment: Swap parameter `net = cv.dnn.readNetFromDarknet('yolov3.cfg', 'yolov3.weights')` And make sure the .cfg and .weights files are in the same dir you're running your python script from.